# Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset()

Tags: php, curl, reset

I am trying to integrate google API login in php, but facing a problem. 
Error message is

> 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GoogleLogin\googleApi\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php
>   on line 78';

even though I remove '`curl_reset()`' on fun but still facing same issue

Comment: Which version of Guzzle do you use? Have you checked whether cURL is available in your PHP installation?

Comment: php5.5 is minimum version for having curl_reset() function. I think your version of PHP is less than php5.5

Comment: "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"

Comment: and php 7.2.2 v i m using

Comment: @NicoHaase  yaa i have checked cUrl is available.

Comment: I want to create google API login using php. have you guys any updated documentation which can I follow and I have already followed few documents which are not working and facing issues.

Answer (score 2):

In your bootstrap file, try to declare the function like this :

```
if (!function_exists('curl_reset')) {
    function curl_reset(&$ch)
    {
        curl_close($ch);
        $ch = curl_init();
    }
}
```

It is an Hack for php < 5.5